# Why is express-session connect.sid value is visible on client?

Tags: node.js, express, security, session, express-session

I was playing around with express-session and reading their documentation and it seems like on the client side, the cookie with the name `connect.sid` stores the session ID. My understanding of security is limited but isn't this a vulnerability if the session ID is so easily accessible?

[image]

Comment: The express-session middleware stores session data on the server; it only saves the session ID in the cookie itself, not session data. According to documentation by express, it is not designed to be used on Production environment.

Comment: @Bibek But with the session ID, malicious users can hijack the session and thus, access session data as well? I think the documentation says if you use another storage method, then it can be used for production. But I'm still having trouble getting the `connect.sid` cookie to be hidden...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are private to the target client.   This is no different for socket.io or for a google login.  If the server wants to protect them, then you run the connection over https and it's end-to-end encrypted and the only one who has access to those cookies is the client itself.  This is how browsers do login and identification of a previously authenticated client.

Also a socket.io sessionID does not need to be a secret.  It doesn't authorize anything.  It just identifies a client as the same client as previous.  If the application wants that client to be authenticated and secure, then that needs to happen some different way.  There is no authentication whatsoever associated with a socket.io cookie.

If you're using an express-session and you want it to be secure, then you need to use end-to-end https.  That protects the session cookie in transit.  Yes, if your client is compromised and someone steals the session cookie and uses it before it expires, they can possibly hijack the session.  But, that's why you use https so there is no way to grab the session cookie from somewhere in the middle of the transport.  So, what needs to be secure is the client itself.  And, that's the same requirement as every single web site that uses authentication.  This is the architecture of the web, nothing new for socket.io or express-session.

> So what would happen if somehow your computer is hacked and the hacker obtains access to the client's browser, and hence the cookies & session ID as well? Then they wouldn't be hijacking the session while it's in transporting

First off, you can expire your cookies quickly (like within 5 minutes of inactivity).  You will see banking websites do this.

Then, you have much bigger problems if the computer itself has been compromised.  The attacker can implant keyloggers or other spyware and can steal your actual login credentials, not only for your website, but also for email and other things like that.

There are higher levels of security than just a username and password for login.  For example, you can require a physical piece of hardware that either plugs into your USB port or requires you to enter a code (that is constantly changing) from the device.  I've worked for companies that required such a device in order to login to the company network from outside the corporate LAN.  This is one form of what is referred to as "two-factor" authentication.

If you look at websites like banks, they will typically do some sort of detection of the login computer and if it looks like an unfamiliar computer (missing other cookies, different IP address, different user agent, different screen resolution, etc...) then they require additional login steps such as sending a code to your phone that you have to enter before you can get logged in.  Or, they require you to answer additional personal questions before letting you in.  They may also notify the account holder that a new computer was used for login.  If that wasn't you, go change/resecure your account credentials.

> Would you suggest setting up a re-route of my entire website from HTTP to HTTPS to solve this?

Yes.   Any site interested in security should require access over https.

There is a lot written about this topic on the web.  You can start by reading articles here: https://www.google.com/search?q=best+practices+for+securing+login

Comment: So what would happen if somehow your computer is hacked and the hacker obtains access to the client's browser, and hence the cookies & session ID as well? Then they wouldn't be hijacking the session while it's in transporting? I'm using sessions for authentication mainly btw.

Also, thanks for the suggestion on using HTTPS! Would you suggest setting up a re-route of my entire website from HTTP to HTTPS to solve this?

And do you have any suggestions on best practices for securing the client itself?

Comment: @Jackson - I added some more to my answer about your recent questions.

Comment: So mostly, I just need to worry about using HTTPS to ensure session IDs can't be hijacked during transport? Because that's the main way that sessions are hijacked?

Comment: @Jackson - Yes for session hijack.  There are other things (some of which are described above) that increase security when credentials are stolen.